# Sorting filenames by conditions

Tags: vba6

I want to create a bit of code that saves a file out to a folder (PDF / DWG ) and moves all my files with a lower revision #5 than the current file being saved into a superseded folder.

I cannot see how to set a condition for the revision number: I can't use a wildcard as that would cause issues as other files in the folder would be picked up and moved incorrectly.

I have the save function sorted, I just dont know were to start with filing part.

Examples of the filenames:

Pdf/TE1801_200-01_{name}_#5.PDF
Dwg/TE1801_200-01_{name}_#5.DWG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' MOVE OLD REVISION TO SUPERSEDED FOLDERS - PDF
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  
  
URLPASS = Filepath & "PDF\"
      

      
Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant
      
Set MyObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MySource = MyObject.GetFolder(URLPASS)
        For Each file_ In MySource.Files



LArray = Split(file_, "#")


checkfile = LArray(0)


REV = Split(LArray(1), ".")


If LArray(0) = checkfile And REV(0) < VERSION Then



' FILE FORMATING
' ----------------------------------------


RECON = Split(file_, "PDF\")

    file_ = RECON(1)

RECON = Split(file_, ".")

    DRAWNOCONFIG = RECON(0)
    
  
' MOVE TO NEW LOCATION
' ----------------------------------------
  
  
If Dir(Filepath & "PDF" & "\SUPERSEDED", vbDirectory) = "" Then '
MkDir Filepath & "PDF" & "\SUPERSEDED"
End If
  
  
Name Filepath & "PDF\" & DRAWNOCONFIG & ".pdf" As Filepath & "PDF\" & "SUPERSEDED\" & DRAWNOCONFIG & ".pdf"




Else
'DO NOTHING
GoTo Endline
End If


Endline:


   Next file_


' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' MOVE OLD REVISION TO SUPERSEDED FOLDERS - DWG
' ------------------------------------------------------------------------------


URLPASS = Filepath & "DWG\"
      

      

      
Set MyObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MySource = MyObject.GetFolder(URLPASS)
        For Each file_ In MySource.Files



LArray = Split(file_, "#")


checkfile = LArray(0)


REV = Split(LArray(1), ".")


If LArray(0) = checkfile And REV(0) < VERSION Then



' FILE FORMATING
' ----------------------------------------


RECON = Split(file_, "DWG\")

    file_ = RECON(1)

RECON = Split(file_, ".")

    DRAWNOCONFIG = RECON(0)
    
  
' MOVE TO NEW LOCATION
' ----------------------------------------
  
  
If Dir(Filepath & "DWG" & "\SUPERSEDED", vbDirectory) = "" Then '
MkDir Filepath & "DWG" & "\SUPERSEDED"
End If
  
  
Name Filepath & "DWG\" & DRAWNOCONFIG & ".dwg" As Filepath & "DWG\" & "SUPERSEDED\" & DRAWNOCONFIG & ".dwg"




Else
'DO NOTHING
GoTo Endline2
End If


Endline2:


   Next file_
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [GetBaseName Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhxzwwe1(v=vs.84).aspx) to get just the filename without the extension

Then use the [INSTRREV Function](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instrrev.php) to find the position of the last "#" (just in case someone used a "#" in the {name} part).

Next use the [LEFT Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/left-function) to get the the "TE1801_200-01_{name}_#" part and now you can add a wildcard to it like "TE1801_200-01_{name}_#*.*". (It doesn't matter whether or not you have the "#" at the end at this stage.)

Prepend the full path and get all the matching files.

Move those files.

*Now* save the current file with its revison number.